# How to display keyboard in iphone ( or any ios devices ) in google chrome dev tools

Tags: google-developers-console

I know that Nexus keyboard in google dev tools and other android phones exists, now the problem is that I cant test the responsiveness of my ios app because of it.

Any help guys will be appreciated.

Comment: Same problem for me